# How can I install the latest version of Evince?

Tags: software-installation, evince

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with Evince 3.4.0. This version of Evince has some bugs (in particular showing patterns) that are fixed in the version 3.8.0. Does anyone know if there is some repository to have Evince up to date? I would prefer this option (repository) but if this can not be done I would accept also a manual installation of the up to date version.

Answer (score 14):

I had Evince 3.6.1.  The way I upgraded, I just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install evince
```

Below are before and after images.

[image]

[image]

**Keep in mind that the current stable release is 3.6.1**.

Or use Synaptic.  If not installed, you can install it by, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

**Edit**

Evince for 12.04 is not available in the repo anymore.  its only available for 12.10, and 13.04.  To get it for other Ubuntu versions, check [here](http://pkgs.org/download/evince) or [here](https://launchpad.net/evince/+packages).

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.  I did it on 2 machines, one worked, and other one didn't.  So I downloaded the file manually, it installed, but wouldn't run.  I will be deleting the answer, if I can't find a solution.

Comment: I did in 2 machines too but it didn't work in both.

Comment: I installed on work machine, it installs, but will not start.  I will keep looking for a little while longer.

Comment: Mitch, can you verify if you answer works?

Comment: @Braiam As stated in my answer, the update worked on one machine, but not the other.  I installed 12.04 fresh today, and tried to install 3.8, but it wasn't available at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince), since that's how it worked initially.  However I came across [This](http://jaliste.blogspot.de/2013/04/the-jhbuild-experience.html), but I didn't have time to test, since I'm slammed at work.

Comment: `evince` is no longer in this repository.

Comment: @GinGordon Thanks for the note.  I have updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: Note: The latest version is 3.14.x series, which isn't pushed to the PPA at this time.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to install via pre-compiled binaries you can end up [breaking your system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387909/something-wrong-with-linux-mints-appearance-after-attempt-on-installing-evince) because of the depencies.

I have lately tackled the same problem and the only way I could solve it was to download the [latest version](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/evince/3.26/) of Evince (in my case it was 3.26) and compile it manually. Luckily, there's a guide to doing [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/gnome/evince.html):

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-compile-warnings=minimum --enable-introspection --disable-static && make
```

In my case I had to manually install 6 extra packages (all in the repo) to successfully run the `.configure` command, but nothing google can't help.

Since this might be useful for Ubuntu users, which are doomed to use a very out-of-date version of Evince, and for the sake of completion, here are the packages I had to install in my Linux Mint 18.2 in order to compile:

`libxml2-dev`
`libsecret-1-dev`
`libnautilus-extension-dev`
`gobject-introspection-dev` or `libgirepository1.0-dev`
`libpoppler-glib-dev`
`itstool`

Comment: After running `./configure` and `make`, we must run `sudo install` or, my recommendation, `checkinstall` in order to have full control of the installed package via the `dpkg` front end.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [GNOME3 launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) repository.

To add it, open a terminal and enter `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 && sudo apt-get update`.
But be aware that this will upgrade (if you do `sudo apt-get upgrade`) all the gnome related packages.

Comment: I added the repository, update and upgrade but evince is still the 3.4.0 version one...

Comment: For Precise it seems that only Gnome 3.4 is available. You can try to install evince from Quantal (12.10)...