# ppa with latest version of evince for 16.04

Tags: updates, ppa, versions, evince

I'm looking for a ppa that has the lastet version of evince. The version I have is `3.18.2`

I tried adding `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` but it doesn't have a better version. **(Warning, stay away from this ppa, it breaks things!)**

*why?*

I'm experiencing bugs with the annotation feature. When I highlight it's done vertically instead of horizontally, and the text annotation's position is offset somehow (probably the same bug). So maybe updating will fix them.

Comment: According to https://askubuntu.com/a/311002/15003, you could manually install the deb for Evince from pkgs.org. I don't know why the gnome3 PPA doesn't have the latest version of Evince though.

Comment: I know there's a .deb available but I'm looking for a ppa because I want to stay up-to-date with any developments. Thanks! @edwinksl

Comment: If you want I'll copy out the evince build (3.24.1) that I have in my personal use ppa for 16.04 to a temp testing ppa. You could test it out, if good I'd consider making it a permament standalone ppa.

Comment: but I don't know how to make a ppa. And wouldn't it need a server to host it? I'm just asking if there's an already existing ppa that has the latest stable version being pushed to it.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I have newer evince in my personal ppa. I don't recommend anyone using that ppa so I am willing to set up a standalone ppa just for evince. However I'm time pressed to really test it so it would only be useful if I get feedback via launchpad email. To that end check here, build should be available within an hr. or so. https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/evince-test

Comment: My main reason for giving myself the build was for the dark theme which I know works great..

Comment: And with some further thought - ultimately this is better suited to a snap install. so for instance you can install the evince snap (currently 3.26). Then you'd need to connect it the `gnome platform snap`.  I think it's pretty straightforward process. So I'll leave the 3.24 ppa up for the moment but it will not get 3.26 or higher..

Comment: Thank you so much doug I tried your ppa and it's working just fine!  Really appreciated. However the bug isn't fixed. I haven't dealt with snaps before. I barely know what they are. Maybe I can try. ...how do you host a ppa? Don't you need a server to do that? @doug

Comment: I tried the 3.26 snap in 16.04. It installs, opens, then nothing. If you try to open a file it only browses files in the snap folder, i.e. 100% useless. The issue with providing a 3.26 evince .deb for 16.04 is it requires libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 @ version 2.36. Due to the insane amount of apps that dep on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 I can't in good conscious provide that in a ppa. To see I did install that version here, nothing seemed to break but the risk seems too great. If you wish to pursue that for youself maybe start a post in Ubuntu forums > general & I'll help you do it for yourself.

Comment: Any solution for this yet? I also wish to update my Evince to 3.31 which gives shortcuts for annotations etc.